# Search Redirect to wrong Page

Tags: silverstripe

Working with SilverStripe I am trying to add search to my website. I have created my own theme, which I am using in my project. Now I am trying to add search in the blog.

In my Page.ss I have added this

```
<div class="search">
    <h3>SEARCH HERE</h3>
    $SearchForm
</div>
```

This code is for adding a search box in the website.

In the config I enable this

```
FulltextSearchable::enable();
```

The problem is that it is redirecting me to old theme search page instead of my own theme.

Comment: did you flush? When you add a new template file the manifest doesn't know about it. So you have to call ?flush on a page. It could also be that in this case your theme isn't known. How did you define it? In DB or using config.yml?

Comment: yes i flush it many time and also it already added in config.yml

Comment: where is your template located? Where is the original? Same sub-folder? And is a template with the same name in mysite? This would overrule everything else...

Comment: yes my both templates are in themes folder and is same 
check here flatblog is the theme I am using
http://prntscr.com/9h71ue